# How do I sort the field value by null in Search API Solr (Drupal 8)?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I want to alter the search API Solr query in Drupal 8 to order by field null in hook_search_api_solr_query_alter(). How do I add my sort expression in the Solr search query? or Do I need to add it in hook_views_query_alter for my search view? Any ideas?

Comment: Answered here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/292014/44595